# How to handle visibility changes for a custom android view/widget

Tags: android, view

I have written a custom view in android. I need to do some processing when visibility of this view is changed. Is there some listener which is called when visibility of a view/widget is changed ?

Edit:

I know how to change the visibility, would like to know if there is a listener which is called when we setVisibility on the view!

Comment: Explain a bit more, please

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Do you want to do that processing within your custom view class?
If so, then why not just override the setVisibility() method, call super(), and then do your custom processing?

Comment: marking this as answer since this solution was provided prior to blackbelt's detailed explaination

Comment: it does not work this way. For example, if you set a view's parent to be invisible, that view's visibility property still could be  visible. Just practice  this and you will find it's true.

Comment: This is a very limited solution.  @William answer below is more general. Additionally there is a onWindowVisibilityChanged for the window.

Answer (score 18):

> I know how to change the visibility, would like to know if there is a
>   listener which is called when we setVisibility on the view!

you have to subclass your `view/widget` and override `setVisibility`, and register a interface on which you will recive the notification. For instance:

```
public class MyView extends View {

  public interface MyListener {
    public void onSetVisibilityCalled();
  }

  public void registerListener(MyListener myListener) {
    this.mListener = myListener;
  }

 public void setVisibility (int visibility) {
   super.setVisibility(visibility);
   if (mListener != null)
     mListener.onSetVisibilityCalled();
 }

}
```

Comment: When the parent view's visibility is changed, setVisibility won't necessarily be called.

Answer (score 14):

You have to subclass the view you want to add a listener to. You then should override [`onVisibilityChanged`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onVisibilityChanged%28android.view.View,%20int%29) instead of `setVisibility`.  `onVisibilityChanged` is triggered when the view's visibility is changed for any reason, including when an ancestor view was changed.

You will need an interface if you want a different class to be notified when your `View`'s visibility changes.

Example:

```
public class MyView extends View {
  private OnVisibilityChangedListener mVisibilityListener;

  public interface OnVisibilityChangedListener {
    // Avoid "onVisibilityChanged" name because it's a View method
    public void visibilityChanged(int visibility);
  }

  public void setVisibilityListener(OnVisibilityChangedListener listener) {
    this.mVisibilityListener = listener;
  }

 protected void onVisibilityChanged (View view, int visibility) {
   super.onVisibilityChanged(view, visibility);

   // if view == this then this view was directly changed.
   // Otherwise, it was an ancestor that was changed.

   // Notify external listener
   if (mVisibilityListener != null)
     mVisibilityListener.visibilityChanged(visibility);

   // Now we can do some things of our own down here
   // ...
 }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To change the visibility of a widget, use the `widget.setVisibility(View.Visible)` or `widget.setVisibility(View.Invisible)` methods.

Comment: I know how to change the visibility, would like to know if there is a listener which is called when we setVisibility on the view!