# How to run a code after a view became invisible?

Tags: android, animation, view, invisible

I want to run a code after a `View` object is **totally INVISIBLE**.

1. If I use alpha animation, the `View` seems to not totally disappear on `AnimationEnd`. I even tried to create a new class (extends `View`) and override method onAnimatonEnd, but it didn't help.(See this link: [android animation is not finished in onAnimationEnd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750939/android-animation-is-not-finished-in-onanimationend))
2. If I just call `View.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)`, I can see that the View object is not totally INVISIBLE when the code starts to run.

Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps call view.setVisibility(View.GONE) in onAnimationEnd?. If you don't want the view to be gone completely how about setting the alpha to 0 in onAnimationEnd so view.setAlpha(0)

Comment: I tried to make the view **invisible** with Alpha animation. Or I tried view.setAlpha(0) without animation. Both of them didn't work

Comment: what about settings the view to gone? or is that something that you cant use?

Answer (score 0):

Check 2nd answer by William (not accepted one) in [How to handle visibility changes for a custom android view/widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16443088/how-to-handle-visibility-changes-for-a-custom-android-view-widget). That way you can listen to visibility change of your view and then run your code.

Answer (score 0):

you should try to set it INVISIBLE from the XML code, like this:

```
<View... android:visibility="gone"/>
or
<View... android:visibility="invisible"/>
```